# How to reset Sony VAIO laptop to factory settings if OS is corrupted and recovery partition is not visible in boot up?

Tags: operating-systems

I have a Sony VAIO laptop that was formatted by mistake. I don’t have the recovery discs.

How do I get it back to factory settings? The recovery partition is not getting accessed on bootup. Is there any way to access it from command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Hop on Sony's website and see if a recovery disk is available. If it is, burn it and use it to kick off the installation. If not, contact your vendor for support.